# Delphi calculate WGS84 intersection of 2 points

Tags: delphi, gis

Hi could anyone tell me or give me some tips on how I would go about calculating the intersection of 2 WGS84 points with bearing  -

Point A + Bearing, Point B + Bearing = point C (intersection of the 2 points)

many thanks
Colin

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is "How can I calculate the intersection point of two line?" (L1 and L2 for the sake of simplicity)

You have to obtain the lines equation y=mx + q that is calculate m and q coefficient for L1 and L2 in order to have two equation:

> y=m1x + q1
>   y=m2x + q2

the intersection is the solution of this linear system

> x = (q1 - q2) / (m2 - m1); y = m2 / (m2-m1) * (q1 - q2) + q2
>   // Please check the equations I writing calculating it on the fly

Your data is two points on an ellipsoid and two angles (bearing):

> P1=[x1; y1], bearing1 = alfa1
>   P2=[x2; y2], bearing1 = alfa2

You have to project the points on a plain in order to use the above linear geometry.
I suppose you have  WGS84 points: use `proj4` api.

So now the problem is to get the classical line equation from the data.
But we can treat the lines in a polar interpretation:

Given a point P0=[x0, y0] and angle (alfa) the line equation P(t) is

> L(t) = [x0 + cos(alfa) * t, y0 + cos(alfa) * t ], with t in the range [-inf, + inf]

So

> L1(t) = [y1 + cos(alfa1) * t, y1 + cos (alfa1) * t] ;
>   L2(t) = [y2 + cos(alfa2) * t, y2 + cos (alfa2) * t] ;

Resolving the above system we have:

> T = (x1- x2) / (cos(alfa2) - cos(alfa1))
>   X = x1 + cos(alfa1) * T
>   Y = y1 + sin(alfa1) * T

your solution is [X, Y].

After that you have to reproject back in wgs84

You can try to avoid projecting the data and use directly the wgs84 coordinates of p1 and P2; the error may be small but you have to check.

(Please check it; I wrote it in the middle of a javascript debuging's session :-)

```
procedure FindIntersection(x1, y2, alfa1, x2, y2, alfa2: double;
  out x, y: double);
var
  t: double;
begin
  t := (x1 - x2) / (cos(alfa2) - cos(alfa1));
  x := x1 + cos(alfa1) * t;
  y := y1 + sin(alfa1) * t;
end; (* Solution without reprojecting *)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, would it be possible to elaberate a bit more as I am no maths genuis and find the above a bit hard to follow

Comment: procedure FindIntersection(x1, y2, alfa1, x2, y2, alfa2 : double; out x,y:double); var t : double; begin t := (x1- x2) / (cos(alfa2) - cos(alfa1)); x := x1 + cos(alfa1) * T; y := y1 + sin(alfa1) * T; end; (* Solution without reprojecting*)

Comment: Hi Stefano,could you verify this is correct as I cannot get it to work I have tried the following - point A 50.681904 -4.0410222 Bearing 130 Deg. Point B 50.673067 -3.9797788 Bearing 10 Deg it Returns 50.688783 -4.0236010 However I think it Should be 50.687215 -3.960828  Could you possibly help further thanks  colin

Answer (score 0):

tack a look:
[Geometry, Surfaces, Curves, Polyhedra](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/)